# Is it possible to infer the return type without explicit casting?

Tags: java, generics, casting, type-inference, builder

In his book *Effective Java* Joshua Bloch describes in *Item 2* a builder pattern using pizzas. I have simplified the example a bit and instead of instantiating the builder directly I want to obtain the corresponding builder depending on an enum value:

```java
public static <T extends Person.Builder<T>> T newBuilder(Template template) {

    return (T) switch (template) {
        case FRIEND -> new Friend.Builder();
        case STRANGER -> null;
    };
}
```

Impractically, I have to cast the builder properly to get access to the subclassed methods. However, the methods of the abstract base class are accessible even without casting:

```java
// works with implicit casting to Friend.Builder
Friend.Builder friendBuilder = newBuilder(Template.FRIEND);
friendBuilder.setNickname("friend");

// works without explicit casting: setDescription (from base class) is accessible
newBuilder(Template.FRIEND).setDescription("very friendly");

// doesn't work without explicit casting: setNickname (from subclass) is not accessible
newBuilder(Template.FRIEND).setNickname("friend");
```

Is there any chance to infer the return type (or cast the selected builder somehow within the switch statement) so that I can use methods from sub classes directly without having to cast the returned builder?

Here the three classes involved in their entirety:

PersonService (main):

```java
public class PersonService {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // works with implicit casting to Friend.Builder
        Friend.Builder friendBuilder = newBuilder(Template.FRIEND);
        friendBuilder.setNickname("friend");

        // works without explicit casting: setDescription (from base class) is accessible
        newBuilder(Template.FRIEND).setDescription("very friendly");

        // doesn't work without explicit casting: setNickname (from subclass) is not accessible
        newBuilder(Template.FRIEND).setNickname("friend");
    }

    public static <T extends Person.Builder<T>> T newBuilder(Template template) {

        return (T) switch (template) {
            case FRIEND -> new Friend.Builder();
            case STRANGER -> null;
        };
    }
}
```

Person:

```java
public abstract class Person {

    private final String description;

    protected Person(Builder<?> builder) {
        this.description = builder.description;
    }

    static abstract class Builder<T extends Builder<T>> {

        private String description;

        public T setDescription(String description) {
            this.description = description;
            return self();
        }

        public abstract Person build();
        
        protected abstract T self();
    }

    public enum Template { STRANGER, FRIEND }
}
```

Friend:

```java
public class Friend extends Person {

    public Friend(Builder builder) {
        super(builder);
    }

    public static class Builder extends Person.Builder<Builder> {

        private String nickname;

        public void setNickname(String nickname) {
            this.nickname = nickname;
        }

        @Override
        public Friend build() {
            return new Friend(this);
        }

        @Override
        protected Builder self() {
            return this;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No. And I suspect you mean "explicit", rather than "implicit".

Comment: Or rather, no, you can't do it if you pass in the same type of "thing" as a parameter to `newBuilder`, and that thing doesn't involve `T`. If you could pass in a `BuilderProvider<T>` (or similar), you could return a `Builder<T>`.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have changed the title to explicit. I will try to figure out how to add your suggested technique, maybe I can pass the information somehow with the enum as property?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Your code smells around the `switch (template)` part. Use some pattern here, like a strategy or similar, to avoid the `swith`ing, and most probably your problem will be solved *eo ipso*.

Comment: @HonzaZidek: This is a pattern, to be more precisely, there are two patterns involved: one is a BuilderFactory, that is the part with the switch statement, and the other is the Builder itself. What I want to achieve is to obtain a specific builder for a class, where the involved classes are hierarchically dependent on each other.

Comment: And which pattern is the usage of `switch`? Please read this: [Seven Ways to Refactor Java switch Statements](https://www.developer.com/design/seven-ways-to-refactor-java-switch-statements/)

Comment: The switch statement is part of the Factory, which decides upon the provided template (the template has to be passed in some way anyway) what Builder to return. Thanks for the link, I'll take a closer look into this. I'm thankful for any help to get my code better.

Comment: @HonzaZidek: I've read the article and must admit, there are some interesting tips to grab. Currently the code I implemented (and posted as excerpt in the question here) is nearly one to one the same as of `5. Relying on Abstract Factory`. So I'm glad to be at least somehow on the right track - even when I think I can do better using `1. Implementing the Strategy Pattern via Java Enum` (also I must confess, I like Josh Bloch ;)) So time for some coffee and redo. Thanks alot.

Comment: Implementing the strategy pattern via Java Enum is good, if the enum is really enum, which means if **there is a "central authority" specifying the complete list of options**, and if the list does not change often. It is still recommendable to implement the strategy pattern traditionally, i.e. via an interface and implementing classes. If each template always generates one type of class, you may also make the `Template` class aware of the type it generates.

Comment: You can't use enums or switches to do this.  You could make the Template type a generic class and have static final instances of it with particular type parameters.